# Unity: Move windows across displays with maximize left/right shortcut

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, compiz, window-manager

I have Ubuntu with Unity running with two monitors. I use the left/right maximize shortcuts quite a lot (can be found in `CompizConfig/Window Management/Grid`).

But there's one additional thing I want this shortcut to do: When I have a window maximized to the right edge of the left screen, I want to be able to hit `right maximize` again to move the window to the right screen. Is there a way to accomplish this? This seems to be standard behavior in KDE, so maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

**Edit:** Versions:

- Ubuntu: 16.04.2 LTS
- Unity: 7.4.0
- Compiz: 0.9.12.2

Answer (score 0):

Start by installing compizconfig settings manager, which it looks like you've already done.  You may need compiz-extras as well.  Then open the compizconfig settings manager.

- Search for and click on the `Put` plugin: enable it.
- Select `Put to adjacent viewport`.
- Set your desired key combination to send a window to the viewport to the left or right.

Bear in mind that you will have to set a different shortcut than anything that is already used by compiz, otherwise you will have keybinding conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, but that keybinding conflict is actually part of my problem. Having just one shortcut to arrange windows is just much smoother.